# How to display number of times a page has been refreshed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this code which displays time when refreshed, but I want to display how many times it has been refreshed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    j('.refresh').click(refreshDiv);

    j('.refresh').css({
        color: ""
    });

    function refreshDiv() {
        j.ajax({
            url: "refresh.php",
            cache: true,
            success: function (html) {
                j(".refresh").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

This code displays time in secs when refreshed. I want to display the number of times the div has been refreshed, like "you have refreshed 9 times".

Comment: Where *specifically* are you stuck?

Comment: Actually I m not stuck its just that I  want to display the number of times I have refreshed.Like when I click the first time It should display you have refreshed once.If again I click on refresh then it should display you have refreshed twice....the code I am having just displays the number of sec when I click on it.

Comment: You're basically saying: Please write this code for me. This site is for asking for **help** with writing your own code, not asking others to do your work for you. Take a stab at it, and if you get stuck on something, ask about *that*.

Answer (score -1):

You can have some global integer variable (*counter*),

which you should increase (+1) in the `success` method just below `j(".refresh").html(html);`

Then, you can display it anywhere at the page.

Also, don't forget to set that counter to `0` when the page is loaded.

Or, you can have the check in the success method:

```
if(counter == undefined) {
    counter = 0;
}
```

Complete code:

```
var counter;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    j('.refresh').click(refreshDiv);

    j('.refresh').css({
        color: ""
    });

    function refreshDiv() {
        j.ajax({
            url: "refresh.php",
            cache: true,
            success: function (html) {
                j(".refresh").html(html);
                if(counter == undefined) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
                counter ++;
                j("#divForCounter").text('refreshed ' + counter + 'times');
            }
        });
    }
});
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

P.S. You should have `div` with id `divForCounter` in your *html*, where the text regarding refreshes will be posted.

Comment: @nileshsurve: It's your responsibility to write your code, not his.

Comment: its not displaying the number of times page is being refreshed. Its just showing time after onclick.

Comment: And .refresh function is not used in this.Its just extracting the date and displaying after onclick .I actually want to refresh the div onclick.